# Code to redirect to another page if answer is correct

Tags: php

I am making an online test. There are 10 levels. The question is picked from database and if the answer is correct then it update the level cleared of that particular user  and show next question on the same page.

But I want to direct the page to another page if the answer is correct whose url is in the database and update the level number of the user as above.
I know how to display question in same page but don't know how to redirect if correct.

Here is the code of simple test where questions are displayed n the same page.

```
<?php
 session_start();
 if(!isset($_SESSION['myusername'])){
 header("location:index.php?unreg=1");
  }
 else {
 $myuser = $_SESSION["myusername"];
  $mypass = $_SESSION["mypassword"];

 $host="localhost"; // Host name 
  $username=""; // Mysql username 
   $password=""; // Mysql password 
  $db_name=""; // Database name 
  $tbl_name="members"; // Table name 
    $tbl_name2="quiz"; // Table name 2

     // Connect to server and select databse.
     mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
   mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

     if(isset($_POST['qno']))
    {
       $sql3="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name2 WHERE id='".$_POST['qno']."'";
    $result3=mysql_query($sql3);

       $disp3=mysql_fetch_assoc($result3);

      $sql4="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myuser' and password='$mypass'";
        $result4=mysql_query($sql4);

      $disp4=mysql_fetch_assoc($result4);

     if($disp3['Answer']==$_POST['Answer'])
     {

     $sql5 ="UPDATE $tbl_name SET level_crossed='".($disp4

   ['level_crossed']   +1)."', Score='    $disp4['Score']+1)."' WHERE 
      username='$myuser' and password='$mypass'";
     $result5=mysql_query($sql5);
         }
         else {
          $sql5="UPDATE $tbl_name SET level_crossed='".($disp4['level_crossed']+1).
         "' WHERE username='$myuser' and password='$mypass'";
         $result5=mysql_query($sql5);

        }

         }

        $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myuser' and password='$mypass'";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);

     $disp=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            echo "    ".$disp['level_crossed']."    ";


          $sql7="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name2 WHERE id='".($disp['level_crossed']+1)."'";
           $result7=mysql_query($sql7);

            $disp2=mysql_fetch_assoc($result7);
               ?>
        <br>
     <?php

      echo "Q.)".$disp2['Question']."    ";
        ?>
          <br>
           <form name="quizq" action="quiz1.php" method="post" >
         <input name="qno" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $disp['level_crossed']+1; ?>" />
          <input type="radio" name="Answer" value="<?php echo $disp2['Option1'];>" /><? 
                                                                                                        php echo $disp2['Option1']; ?><br>
      <input type="radio" name="Answer" value="<?php echo $disp2['Option2']; ?>" />
          <?php  echo $disp2['Option2']; ?><br>
      <input type="radio" name="Answer" value="<?php echo $disp2['Option3']; ?>" />
     <?php echo $disp2['Option3']; ?><br>
      <input type="radio" name="Answer" value="<?php echo $disp2['Option4']; ?>" />
       <?php echo $disp2['Option4']; ?><br>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit Answer" />
        </form>
     <br><br>
         <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
   <?php


     }
    ?>
```

Comment: Was there meant to be some code listed?

Comment: Meh, we don't need to see it anyway

Comment: Mysql_ is deprecated, use PDO or mysqli instead

Comment: I have added the whole code.

Comment: PDO is the least concern when they're storing passwords IN PLAIN TEXT

Answer (score 3):

To redirect to another url:

```
header('Location: /path/of/next/page');
```

Just like any other `header`, you cannot have any output rendered before calling `header`. This includes `echo`, `print`, and any text outside of `php` tags.

Comment: Just a nitpicking comment - an HTTP header location should technically use an absolute URI (http://www.server.com/path/of/next/page). [HTTP Header Location](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30)

Comment: Relative to the documentroot (`/path`) is fairly unambiguous. Relative to the current page (`page2.php`) I would not recommend.

Comment: Oh, I agree it's not ambiguous... just going off the defined standard! Nitpicking!  ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect the page using headers

```
header( 'Location: http://www.url.com/' );
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use `header`
For example:
`header( 'Location: test.php' );`